# How to use a template in vim

Tags: r, vim

This is really a newbie question - but basically, how do I enable a template for certain filetypes.

Basically, I just want the template to insert a header of sorts, that is with some functions that I find useful, and libraries loaded etc.

I interpret

```
:help template
```

the way that I should place this in my vimrc

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead ~/.vim/skeleton.R
```

Running a R script then shows that something could happen, but apparently does not:

```
--- Auto-Commands ---
```

This may be because a template consists of commands (and there are no such in skeleton.R) - and in this case I just want it to insert a text header (which skelton.R consist of).

Sorry if this question is mind boggeling stupid ;-/

Comment: Is it just me or is there a blank line added before the template everytime on the creation of a new file?  Anyway to rid of the newline?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The command that you've suggested is not going to work: what this will do is run no Vim command whenever you open `~/.vim/skeleton.R`

A crude way of achieving what you want would be to use:

```
:au BufNewFile *.R r ~/.vim/skeleton.R
```

This will read (`:r`) your file whenever a new `*.R` file is created.  You want to avoid having `BufRead` in the autocmd, or it will read the skeleton file into your working file every time you open the file!

There are many plugins that add a lot more control to this process.  Being the author and therefore completely biased, I'd recommend [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2647), but there are plenty of others listed [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

---

Shameless plug:

They all work in a relatively similar way, but to explain my script:

You install the plugin as described on the [linked](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2647) page and then create some templates in `~/.vim/templates`.  These templates should have the same extension as the 'target' file, so if it's a template for `.R` files, call it something like `skeleton.R`.  In your `.vimrc`, add something like this:

```
let g:file_template_default = {}
let g:file_template_default['R'] = 'skeleton'
```

Then create your new `.R` file (with a filename, so save it if it's new) and enter:

```
:LoadFileTemplate
```

You can also skip the `.vimrc` editing and just do:

```
:LoadFileTemplate skeleton
```

See [the website](https://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/file-templates) for more details.

Comment: Beauti-forking-full - very good answer - walking me through the steps. Thanks alot. For now the crude method works for what I had intended, but I have downloaded the extension, and will see how I can use it :-) - thanks.

Comment: Use `0r` instead of `r` and the insertion will not add in a blank line.

Answer (score 10):

Assume that your skeletons are in your ~/.vim/templates/ directory, you can put this 
snippet in your vimrc file.

```
augroup templates
  au!
  " read in templates files
  autocmd BufNewFile *.* silent! execute '0r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.'.expand("<afile>:e")
augroup END
```

Some explanation,

- BufNewFile *.*  = each time we edit a new file
- silent! execute = execute silently, no error messages if failed
- 0r = read file and insert content at top (0) in the new file
- expand(":e") = get extension of current filename

see also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_eval_to_create_dynamic_templates

*fixed missing dot in file path

Answer (score 8):

Create a *templates* subdirectory in your `~/.vim` folder

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/templates
```

Create a new file in subdirectory called **R.skeleton** and put in the header and/or other stuff you want to automagically load upon creating a new "*.R* " file.

```
$ vim ~/.vim/templates/R.skeleton
```

Then, add the following to your `~/.vimrc` file, which *may* have been suggested in a way by "guest"

```
autocmd BufNewFile * silent! 0r $HOME/.vim/templates/%:e.skeleton
```

Have a look at [my github repository](https://github.com/ILMostro/vimUser-Home) for some more details and other options.

Comment: This looks like the shortest answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's just a trick I used to use . 
It's cheap but If you ain't know nothing about vim and it's commands it's easy to handle.
make a directory like this :

```
~/.vim/templates/barney.cpp
```

and as you konw barney.cpp should be your template code .
then add a function like `ForUncleBarney()` to end of your .vimrc file located in `~/.vimrc`
it should be like

```
function ForBarneyStinson()
   :read ~/.vim/templates/barney.cpp
endfunction
```

then just use this command in vim

```
:call ForBarneyStinson()
```

then you see your template
as an example I already have two templates for .cpp files

```
:call ForBarney()
:call ACM()
```

sorry said too much,
Coding's awesome ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template.git.

I use it and have contributed some patches to it and would argue its relatively full featured.

Answer (score 1):

There exist many [template-file expanders](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion) -- you'll also find there explanations on how to implement a rudimentary template-file expander.

For my part, I'm maintaining the fork of [muTemplate](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template). For a simple start, just drop a `{ft}.template` file into `{rtp}/template/`. If you want to use any (viml) variable or expression, just do. You can even put vim code (and now even functions) into the template-file if you wish. Several smart decisions are already implemented for C++ and vim files.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the snipmate plugin? See [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vim.org%2Fscripts%2Fscript.php%3Fscript_id%3D2540&rct=j&q=snipmate&ei=TrecTKHmO8mJ4gah8pWIDQ&usg=AFQjCNGd7EMyLiyEaGO3vMz_LQ4orZ21qw&sig2=2llq7Y3ODgmrx_iFY2xXoQ&cad=rja)