# How can I start vim by inserting the date and some text at the beginning of the file?

Tags: vim

I'm working on a bash script to create log files something like this, where the latest entry appears first in file:

```
2019-07-26 Looks like SSD needs replacing
2019-07-25 db backup failed
```

If no text is included on command line, just start vim. 
If text is included on the command line, insert date and that text, e.g.

```
edlog db backup failed
```

Conceptually it looks like this in my head but only the first -c command works as expected:

```
!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    nvim ~/log.txt
else
  # :r will Insert date at top of file.
  # $\t moves to end of line and inserts a tab
  # $* appends contents of command line
  nvim -c ":r! date +\%F"  -c "$\t" -c "$*" ~/log.txt
fi
```

Comment: A bit late to the party, but maybe you want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785320/how-to-use-a-template-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I'm very much open to criticism and corrections.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Appends to a log file if you type a message, or
# just brings up vim in case you want to log several
# lines' worth
# Nothing added to command line, so just bring up vim:
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    nvim ~/Dropbox/log.txt
else
  # User entered something like this:
  #   edlog Extra backup last night due to OS update
  LINE="  $*"
  # Format date like 07/25/2019
  # Start inserting text after the date.
  # Insert all arguments on command line, like "Re-test db"
  # Then write out file, and quit back to shell
  nvim -c ":pu=strftime('%m/%d/%Y')" -c ":startinsert!" -c "norm a$LINE" -c "wq" ~/Dropbox/log.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A quasi-vim centric solution:

```sh
date > file
echo "$@" >>file
vim file +'0join'
```

Using vim commands:

```
vim +'0r !date' +'0d' +"normal! A<Tab>$@"
```

Where `<Tab>` is a literal tab character.

Or with ex:

```
ex <<EOF file
0r !date
0d
normal! A<Tab>$@
wq
EOF
```