# Vim: Create a template for Latex

Tags: vim, latex

I have created this VimScript function to automatically generate a template for newly created latex files (with `*.tex` extension)

```
function CreateLatexTemplate()
    normal ggi\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    normal o\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    normal o\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    normal o\usepackage{amsmath}
    normal o\usepackage{amsfonts}
    normal o\usepackage{amssymb}
    normal o\usepackage{graphicx}
    normal o\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}
    normal o\author{Author Name}
    normal o\begin{document}
    normal o\end{document}
    normal ko
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile *.tex call CreateLatexTemplate()
```

So far it works just fine. But as you can see that I am repeating myself several times in the function `CreateLatexTemplate`.

Could someone please suggest a better alternative to my syntax?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blatex%5D+%5Bvim%5D+snippets

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a better alternative for this syntax, but I want to suggest a different approach.

You may be interested in snippets which are essentially templates that make it easier to enter repeating code patterns. Here is a demo from the [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) repo that shows how it works:

[image]

You just need to install the snippets plugin and create a snippet from your template to use it in your work.

This is quite popular approach to writing complex LaTeX documents, you could see [this post](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) for more inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using snippet plugin, you can also use a template plugin like [vim-template](https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template), see also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3785320/6064933).